# Fixing "Can't find variable: mapboxgl" Issue

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, issue-tracking

I am not good a JS at all but after following the examples from the MAPBOX website I am unable to render a map at all.  Code is exactly as it should be according to the website.  The only error that shows up `Can't find variable: mapboxgl`.  After researching this I have not found anything on this.  What am I doing wrong?

MyCode:

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<? print $mapboxapi; ?>';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
center: [<? print $SQL["long"] ?>, <? print $SQL["lat"] ?>], // starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
         
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat([<? print $SQL["long"] ?>, <? print $SQL["lat"] ?>])
.addTo(map);
</script>
```

This renders out this code:

```
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
center: [-00.00000, 00.000000000], // starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
                                                    
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat([-00.00000, 00.000000000])
.addTo(map);
</script>
```

[image: error repeats after every SQL row that is rendered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't included the necessary script and CSS files in your `<head>` section. These bits:

```
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I have included both in the header of my script.  As I said I did everything as instructed here. [link](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-a-marker/)

Comment: Correction!  You were right.  I was loading the JS in the foot of the script and not the header on accident.  Putting the JS in the <head> fixed that issue.  Thank you!